# Injective map of abelian group and product of cyclic quotients

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $A$ be an abelian group. We have a map from $A \to \prod{(A/I)}$ where $A/I$ varies over the cyclic quotients of $A$. This map is given by sending $x$ to $\prod (x \text{ mod } I)$. Is this map injective?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Let $A=\mathbb{Q}$.  Since $A$ is divisible, all quotients of $A$ are.  In particular, $A$ has no nontrivial cyclic quotients.  So $\prod (A/I)$ is trivial.

Answer (score 3):

To complement @user10354138's answer:

It's true iff $A$ is residually finite.

If $A$ is a torsion-free abelian group, it is residually finite if and only if it does not contain any subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbf{Q}$. Actually, a torsion-free abelian group always decomposes (non-canonically) as direct sum $A_{\mathrm{div}}\oplus B$, where $A_{\mathrm{div}}$ is its subgroup of divisible elements (this is a vector space over $\mathbf{Q}$), and a residually finite abelian group $B$.

Comment: Thank you! I just found out that it's also assumed that A is a profinite group in my notes. Then it works.

Comment: In this case you can even consider the embedding into the product of cyclic Hausdorff quotients (i.e., those finite cyclic quotients for which the kernel is an open subgroup), and get a closed embedding, which is a homeomorphism onto its image.